# What does --routing-scope stands for in Angular CLI

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6

In angular CLI when creating module we can add --routing-scope as a parameter.

```
ng g m dashboard --routing-scope something-here --routing
```

when using this command I get error:

```
Schematic input does not validate against the 
Schema: {"routingScope":"dashboard","routing":false,"spec":true,"flat":false,"commonModule":true}
Errors: Data path ".routingScope" should be equal to one of the allowed values.
```

But what are the allowed values?

This parameter is not described in the docs.

Comment: Maybe check out the docs

Comment: @Li357 It's not described in the docs

Comment: @Tukkan , they are mentioned here : https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/generate-module

Comment: @CruelEngine yes but "The scope for the generated routing." is all what is written and what I could deduce from the parameter name but it's still not fully clear.  Is it the name of the root in main rooting configuration or something different? I tried multiple values and combinations and all of them are returning the above mentioned error.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

After some digging, I found this: [schema.json](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/fd14e4e162cfdd5f36a6447aea7143b94a159d58/packages/angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json), the *schema.json* for the CLI. Lots of good stuff in this.

According to this, the valid values for `--routing-scope` are either `Child`, or `Root`. Casing matters. The default is `Child`.

An odd thing is, the code that gets generated looks exactly the same no matter what value I use. They both look like what is below after running `ng g m testing --routing-scope Child` or `ng g m testing --routing-scope Root`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: []
})
export class TestingModule { }
```

Further digging [shows](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/44086c60ff1d6c26d30850bef125120f6c498ac1/packages/schematics/angular/module/files/__name%40dasherize%40if-flat__/__name%40dasherize__-routing.module.ts) that the value is used when code is generated to build the `forRoot` or `forChild` function in module `imports`.

Comment: Ok. So basically forRoot is used anyways when using `ng new projectName --routing` and when creating submodule with `--routing` parameter the Child is the default value and this totally makes sense. Thanks!